# sort array of objects recursively for all children

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a array of objects which has many level of nested children, I need to sort this by comparing two properties of same level items. Array has multiple nested items, so I came with this minimal array which needs to be sorted.

Every item will have minimum 3 properties (path, title & previous), and some of the items might have similar items as children.

```
// unsorted array
const original = [
  {
    "path": "path3",
    "title": "title3",
    "previous": "title2",
    "children": [
      { "path": "child31", "title": "child31", "previous": null },
      { "path": "child32", "title": "child32", "previous": "child31" },
      { "path": "child33", "title": "child33", "previous": "child32" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "path": "path1",
    "title": "title1",
    "previous": null,
    "children": [
      { "path": "child11", "title": "child11", "previous": null },
      { "path": "child13", "title": "child13", "previous": "child12" },
      { "path": "child14", "title": "child14", "previous": "child13" },
      { "path": "child12", "title": "child12", "previous": "child11",
        "children": [
          { "path": "child123", "title": "child123", "previous": "child122" },
          { "path": "child121", "title": "child121", "previous": null },
          { "path": "child122", "title": "child122", "previous": "child121",
            "children": [
              { "path": "child1221", "title": "child1221", "previous": null, 
                "children": [
                  {
                    "path": "child12211",
                    "title": "child12211",
                    "previous": null
                  },
                  {
                    "path": "child1222",
                    "title": "child1222",
                    "previous": "child1221"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "path": "child1224",
                "title": "child1224",
                "previous": "child1223"
              },
              {
                "path": "child1222",
                "title": "child1222",
                "previous": "child1221"
              },
              {
                "path": "child1223",
                "title": "child1223",
                "previous": "child1222",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "path": "child12231",
                    "title": "child12231",
                    "previous": null
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
      ]}
    ]
  },
  { "path": "path2", "title": "title2", "previous": "title1" }
];
```

I need to sort this array by comparing previous and title values of the items within same parent. If previous is null of any items, that will be the first item in that parent, and for next item previous will be title of it's previous sibling and so on.

Here is my sorting function:

```
const sortNav = items => {
  let result = [...items].sort(function (a, b) {
    if(a.title === b.previous || a.previous === null) {
      return -1;
    } 
    if (a.previous === b.title || b.previous === null) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  })

  for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].children && items[i].children.length) {
      items[i].children = sortNav(items[i].children);
    }
  }
  return result;
};
```

I am consuming function like this

```
const sorted = sortNav(original);
```

[original array](https://pastebin.com/qHwMWj7L)

[original sorted array](https://pastebin.com/qHwMWj7L)

Comment: You should include your initial data as well as your desired result within your question

Comment: @Gershom inital data is on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/qHwMWj7L), I don't have expected data, will update question with this

Comment: which entries have you found with a wrong precedence when sorted?

Comment: @MadanBhandari it may be helpful if you can provide a more minimal initial dataset and its expected result, so that we can understand what you want more concisely

Comment: @Tibebes.M wrong sort in inner (3rd or more) children

Comment: @Gershom I couldn't figure out exact problem, not sure how much smaller data will do, for 1st and 2nd level children, sorting works as expected

Comment: if there are 2 nodes with `previous=null`(2 linked lists) in a single array, is it okay for the 2 linked lists to interleave or you want to preserve the linked list order (like `null -> a -> b -> null -> c -> d ..` )?

Comment: @Tibebes.M It's okay to interleave, in this case aren't they considered equal (returning 0) ?

Comment: I've noticed the error you mentioned (around the Object with 'Reference' as title, right?). For some reason, returning -1 instead of 0 at the end of the comparator func. solves the issue. But I don't know why that's is. Take a time and check it..

Answer (score 0):

I would say you need to define a sort function and pass it recursively like so

```
var origArray = ['a','b','c',['a','b','c']];

function SortRecursive(a, b){
 let aArray = Array.isArray(a);
 let bArray = Array.isArray(b);

 if(aArray == bArray){
  if(aArray){
   a.sort(SortRecursive);
   b.sort(SortRecursive);
   return a[0] > b[0] ? -1 : a[0] < b[0] ? 1 : 0;
  } else {
   return a > b ? -1 : a < b ? 1 : 0;
  }
 } else {
  return aArray && !bArray ? -1 : !aArray && bArray ? 1 : 0;
 }
}

origArray.sort(SortRecursive);
```

this might not be exactly as how you want to sort your data as we didn't get an example of what your data is but you should be able to see what im doing with the sub arrays.

As a side not this will also sort the same array multiple times so should probably come up with a way to identify sub arrays that have already been sorted.

Comment: I have added sample input and output array.

Comment: well theres your problem you cannot sort Objects it just doesn't work you can sort arrays of objects bot not the contents of an object

Comment: This is an array of objects

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're sorting children of the `items` object, but returning the `result` object from the function. So, sort the children **BEFORE** sorting the list.

```js
const sortNav = items => {

  for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].children && items[i].children.length) {
      console.log("calling sort for children of ", items[i].title, items[i].children)
      items[i].children = sortNav(items[i].children);
    }
  }
 
  let result = [...items].sort(function (a, b) {
    if(a.title === b.previous || a.previous === null) {
      console.log("comparing ...", a.pathTitle, " > ", b.pathTitle)
      return -1;
    } 
    if (a.previous === b.title || b.previous === null) {
      console.log("compare ...", a.pathTitle, " < ", b.pathTitle)
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  })

  console.log("sorted =>", result);
  
  return result;
};
```

This should take care of the children not being sorted. But given your sample data, I also notice that for cases like the following two elements, the sort function returns 0, which means the elements around it are never sorted properly.

```js
[{
  "pathTitle": "set-up-standard-payments.md",
  "title": "Set up standard payments",
  "previous": "credit and debit card payments"
},
{
  "pathTitle": "configure-payments",
  "title": "Configure Payments",
  "previous": "Add capabilities",
  "children": [
    {
      "pathTitle": "alternative-payment-methods.md",
      "title": "Payment Methods",
      "previous": null
    }
  ]
}]
```

Given that you're kind of / sort of trying to reorder a list like a linked list, i suggest using the following function instead :-

```js
const reoderList = (items) => {
 var result = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].children && items[i].children.length) {
      items[i].children = reorderList(items[i].children);
    }
  }
    
  items.forEach(item => {
    if(item.previous === null) {
        result = [item, ...result];
    }
    else {
      var index = result.findIndex(r => r.title === item.previous);
      if(index > -1) {
        result.splice(index+1,0,item);
      }
      else {
        result = [...result,item];
      }
    }
  });
  return result;
};
```

Edit: From the expected output, you also need the previous === null objects to always show up on top. That would probably need a second pass on the result list to ensure that.